# How to access my PHP application on heroku

Tags: php, git, web-services, codeigniter, heroku

Hi guys I have done the deploy of my PHP appplication on heroku but I don't know what I need do now for acess my application, on my local host (Xampp) I used to acess with this url https://localhost/sistemacrm/ and on heroku after followed this steps:

```
$ heroku login
$ heroku git:clone -a sistemacrm
$ cd sistemacrm
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```

I receive this url https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/sistemacrm/deploy/heroku-git and when I open this i receive ERROR 404, also i developed this app with codeigniter

Answer (score 2):

You can get the URL for your Heroku-hosted app from:

1. The end of the build log, after doing `git push heroku master`, the URL should be indicated there (assuming the build/deploy was successful). Something like:

   > Launching... done
   >   https://your-app-name.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
2. The Settings page of your app in Heroku's dashboard. Based on the URL you posted, it's probably at  https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/sistemacrm/settings. Then go to the "Domain and certificates" section to find something like this:

   > Your app can be found at https://your-app-name.herokuapp.com/

I suggest you read the [documentation for deploying PHP apps on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-php#deploy-your-application-to-heroku).
Because it's explicitly described there how to access your app.

Comment: But my doutb is because when I use the localhost, my default index is my login page, so when I type https://localhost/sistemacrm/ the sistem direct open my login page, on heroku how I do for acess my login method, also i developed this app with codeigniter

Comment: The default/homepage depends on your site configuration (your route definitions). Heroku will just use the same config, which allows you to test/dev locally (on your localhost) then the deployed site on Heroku should have the same behavior (ex. same home page). Have you tried accessing the Heroku URL (ex. `https://your-app-name.herokuapp.com` or whatever is displayed in the logs and Settings page)? What page appears?

Comment: What I mean is that the same routes on your localhost should be the same routes on Heroku, unless your app has some special configurations for production/deployed versions.